# Ruby reading/saving plist: how to keep string indentation?

Tags: ios, ruby, rubygems, plist

I'm updating a plist file using Ruby's gem `plist` and upon saving its default formatting breaks the string value with newline:

before:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>message</key>
    <string>This is the first line.

this should be the second line.</string>
</dict>
```

after:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>message</key>
    <string>This is the first line.

    this should be the second line.</string>
</dict>
```

When I read the message in iOS app it's displayed as:

```
This is the first line.

this should be the second line.
```

However after the default formatting it's displayed as:

```
This is the first line.

    this should be the second line.
```

Is there a way to keep the indentation unchanged? (I know the `plist` gem lets you specify what indentation to use (default is tab) but it applies to each single case where indentation is used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), at most anyone can do is guess at what what exactly you're doing to cause this result.

My guess: You'll have to look at [how the gem works](https://github.com/patsplat/plist/blob/f97cf75908d1e8aecdace45174eba9de6bfcf7bf/lib/plist/generator.rb#L134). Notably, check how it implements [`IndentedString#<<`](https://github.com/patsplat/plist/blob/f97cf75908d1e8aecdace45174eba9de6bfcf7bf/lib/plist/generator.rb#L201).

The gem implements multiple ways to "write values", and I bet whatever you're using is doing the `block.call` that returns an array whose individual elements will [always be independently indented](https://github.com/patsplat/plist/blob/f97cf75908d1e8aecdace45174eba9de6bfcf7bf/lib/plist/generator.rb#L134).

Try using one of the other generation methods like [raw verbatim `String` values](https://github.com/patsplat/plist/blob/master/lib/plist/generator.rb#L104) to output an un-indented value.

Answer (score 0):

If formatting is not your concern, you can use [plist_lite](https://github.com/tonytonyjan/plist_lite).

For example, run the following command:

```sh
ruby -rplist_lite -e 'puts PlistLite.dump(PlistLite.load($stdin.read))' <<EOS
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>message</key>
    <string>This is the first line.

this should be the second line.</string>
</dict>
</plist>
EOS
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"><plist version="1.0"><dict><key>message</key><string>This is the first line.

this should be the second line.</string></dict></plist>
```

Not like `plist`, the design of `plist_lite` is quite simple, there is no fancy features like formatting or marshaling, and only have 2 APIs, `PlistLite#load` and `PlistLite#dump`. (the interface is like the built-in `JSON` or `YAML`).

`plist_lite` is over 5 times faster then `plist` because it's written in C. If you are aware of performance, I think you can give it a try.